# How to configure MySQL to automatically decrypt data/images request?

Tags: mysql, django

I am building a `Django` app that allows user to upload images to `MySQL` and the app also displays the uploaded images to users from `MySQL`. I plan to encrypt the file path that stores those images. Is there a way to configure `MySQL` to automatically decrypt **data/images** when my `Django` app queries the database for those encrypted **image/file** path?

Comment: The answer is no to relying on mysql to encrypt the data automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Model methods provide a nice way to organize this code

```
class Example(models.model):
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_filepath(self):
        return decryption_magic(self.filepath)

    def set_filepath(self, filepath):
        self.filepath = encryption_magic(filepath)
```

Comment: So this code is for models.py in the app? seems "decryption_magic" field means i need to pip install magic?

Comment: Yes, this would be in the models.py.   However, it seems that the real answer is to encrypt the entire DB at rest, allowing the DB engine to to the hard work.

Comment: If i were to encrypt the entire DB, would that mean that if my app would like to retrieve a file/image path from the DB, will the DB be able to automatically decrypt the requested fields and serve it to my app?

Comment: Using whole DB encryption means that you dont have to do any encryption in your code.  What are you trying to protect against?

Comment: I'm trying to protect against unauthorised third parties from reading the database fields, especially the file paths. What I am concerned is if the DB is able to decrypt and serve the images to my views.py/html if the entire DB has been encrypted, without me having to do any decryption coding on my app or the database

Comment: I think that you might need to take a larger look at the architecture here. Ask yourself what your threat model is, and what you are trying to achieve. ie. re-phrase the question from a higher level.